# Can we track Microsoft Delta changes on the Users, Group, ChatMessage or Planner Objects based on time. "/me/planner/all/delta"

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-planner

Basically does any one know how to ask for delta changes that happened after certain time. I am saving all the changes that user has done to planner objects to the database, but I know eventually delta changes for 100 of plans will go insanely huge. **GET /me/planner/all/delta GET /users/{id}/planner/all/delta**. Does any one knows how to filter delta response with given time. My plan is to query delta after certain time.
It could be in any object that delta works. Right now I can bring all the delta changes but I do not see how I can ask for changes that happend after certain time.

Answer (score 1):

Delta only works with the tokens presented in the links, it is not time based (we do not store it based on time internally). It is also best-effort, which means at certain time the delta changes will be cleared and the clients will be forced to read objects again to be in sync. So even if there was a time based query, there wouldn't be a guarantee that you can access older data.

What is your scenario? Some kind of history tracking or auditing?

Comment: Basically, I am storing planner objects including tasks, taskdetails, buckets, and etc in the database. Instead of querying for each plan again and again to see changes, I am pulling the delta changes to plans and its objects. Even that delta changes will grow big some day so I was thinking if I can filter delta query to get changes from only certain time so I do not refresh all the delta changes again. I am sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: Why do you need the all deltas? The purpose of delta is to allow you to update your local storage. Why don't you simply apply the change from the delta to your stored object and discard the delta?

Comment: yes, that was my plan but I am just worried if the deltas going to be big if 100s of people start making changes on the same plan. Anyways,  do you know what is the life expectancy of a delta query? I did a get request on the delta query after 3 days and it was expired.

Comment: There is no fixed life expectancy for the delta being available. It depends on the resources and some system processes.
I still don't get your scenario, if you don't store the deltas, why would it matter if they are big? Ideally, you'd get the deltas, update your state in your for each object, then discard the delta. As long as you are not waiting for a very long time the each delta to process should be small enough to not cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, nope. I have to cycle on all Planner plans and tasks in them to get the details. I am currently saving the planner task details to sharepoint and instead of updating it I am just deleting all old records and recreating them.

Comment: Thank for the response  I am storig all plan details in the database and I only want to update the plan that have changed from certain time. Instead for quering all the planner objects again and again.

Comment: I have scheduled the program to run 4 times a day and it usually takes less than 10 minutes to retrieve all task details (we have currently 355 tasks in 20 plans across multiple teams), but will definitely watch this thread to see if you have succeeded in updating via delta :-) let us know the solution if you succeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense, I was saving the deltas so that in future I could tell which user modified what planner objects. Since Microsoft has not implemented an audit trail for planner objects yet. Storing delta Link was just for my possible future rollback processes. 
I realized deltaLink does not expire it is just using delta token to find the future changes from the time the delta was queried. Basically, I am requesting Microsoft teams to have some kind of audit trail for Planner objects changes(at least for who changed at what time) so we can query those activities and have those specific individuals held responsible for unwanted changes that they made. For instance, changing the due date of planner tasks